# wp_insert_post_data filter to set category

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories

I am trying to set additional "default" categories. I figured by hooking into the `wp_insert_post_data` filter, I could use `$postarr` to set the category. It doesn't seem to be working? Can someone offer advice as to how I would go about doing this?

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 's3x9s_wp_insert_post_data', '99', 2 );
function s3x9s_wp_insert_post_data( $data, $postarr ) {
    array_push( $postarr['post_category'], 123 );
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to set the default category is in the `wp-admin`: *Settings* > *Writings* > *Default post Category* However, I think you're looking for setting more than one category by default.

If you look the documentation of [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data), there isn't any key such as `post_category`.

Perhaps, you should use `publish_post`

> Runs when a post is published, or if it is edited and its status is "published". Action function arguments: post ID.

There, you should use [`wp_set_post_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories)

So, the code would be something similar to this:

```
function set_category_by_default( $post_ID ) {
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(123, 124) ) ;
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'set_category_by_default', 5, 1 );
```

Comment: should the function check that no category has been specified for the said post before setting the 'default' categories?